# Installing Leiningen for use with Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to install Leiningen on my local machine to get Clojure running, but I can't seem to get the latest version.

I'm following the instructions on github here: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen

I'm able to put the script in my path, and get Lein to download, but for some reason when I run `lein version` I keep getting

```
Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_33 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

I've tried deleting and re-installing Leiningen several times, but nothing changes. Are there certain files I need to be deleting, or is there some way to switch versions? `lein upgrade` doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

An easier way of upgrading (if using homebrew) is to upgrade using homebrew and specify the version.

1. Show available versions

   ```
    brew info leiningen
    leiningen: stable 1.7.1, devel 2.0.0-preview10, HEAD
   ```
2. Install or upgrade to a specific version

   ```
   brew upgrade --devel leiningen
   ...
   /usr/local/Cellar/leiningen/2.0.0-preview10: 5 files, 80K, built in 10 seconds
   ```
3. Use lein as normal

   ```
   lein version
   Leiningen 2.0.0-preview10 on Java 1.7.0_06 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Check this guide: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading

The trick is to download the script from the preview branch on the github repo:

```
# Make a backup of your previous lein
mv ~/bin/lein ~/bin/lein1
# Download preview version
wget -O ~/bin/lein https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein
# set permissions
chmod 755 ~/bin/lein
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. I had previously tried to install Leiningen via Homebrew, and the Homebrew lein command was somehow superseding the lein commands from the new version I had installed through the script.

I ran the command:

```
brew uninstall leiningen
```

Then I re-installed lein via the new lein script just be safe, first removing the following files & folders:

```
~/.lein
~/.m2
~/bin/lein
```

Now when I run `lein version` I get:

```
Leiningen 2.0.0-preview10 on Java 1.6.0_33 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Answer (score 2):

There's constant `LEIN_VERSION` at the top of the `lein` script. Try changing it a more recent version (mine is `2.0.0-preview10`), delete the leiningen jar in `~/.lein/self-installs/` and run `lein self-install` again.

Answer (score 1):

To completely wipe out your existing Leiningen installation:

```
rm ~/bin/lein
rm -fr ~/.lein  # Though back up ~/.lein/profiles.clj if you have one.
rm -fr ~/.m2
```

then follow the "If you want a newer version it's still easy to install the old-fashioned way" instructions at http://leiningen.org/ .

> Incidentally, if you happen to have a ~/bin/lein2 lying around, and have no need of any legacy lein 1.x (which, in your case, you don't), you can delete that ~/bin/lein2 file. You just want a ~/bin/lein going forward.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue make sure you update brew

```
$brew update
```

then

```
$brew install leiningen --devel
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to install a specific version of lein, an "easy" way to do so is by looking for the  commit of the desired version on the install script https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein

Download and run this script as your `lein` binary and it should just work. The actual version jar will be downloaded to `~/.lein/self-installs`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30307568)